# What happened to my GitHub repository?

Tags: github-enterprise

We have several repo's In an on-premise GitHub.
One of them is missing...
We can re-create it, but is there any way to see the history on that?
Like who deleted it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the admin to see the audit log: https://help.github.com/articles/reviewing-the-audit-log-for-your-organization/